# How to check for repeating sequence in an integer

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I have an alpha-numeric string and I want to check for pattern repetition in it just for the integers. And they should be continuous.

**Example**

1. *12341234qwe* should tell me *1234* is repeated.
2. *1234qwe1234* should **NOT** tell me that *1234* is repeated since its not continuous.
3. *12121212* should be treated as *12* being repeated as that is the first set which would be found being repeated. But if there is an algorithm which would find *1212* as the repeated set before *12* then I guess it has to perform the steps again on *1212*.

What I thought was I can store the integer part by iterating and comparing it with `( <= '0' && >= '9')` in a different `StringBuilder`. Then I read about performing FFT on the string and it shows the repeated patterns. But I have no idea on how to perform FFT in Java and look for the results, also, I was hoping to try to do this without going to Signal Processing. I read about KMP pattern matching but that only works with a given input. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: is there a max number of integers in sequence?

Comment: Nope, there is not limit to the repetition.

Comment: would "12121212" be: a) "1212" repeated two times or b) "12" repeated four times?

Comment: Please add references for special terms you use in your question, but which you don't want to explain. Of course, we can search for them by ourselves, but that does not help with potential ambiguity. Further, such references would make things easier and improve your question.

Comment: @danbystrom: I have edited the question. Michael, I think I have provided the special case which I can think off, if there are more which I come across I would definitely update. Thanks! And This is not homework.

Comment: So, if the input is 123445123445, do you want to say that 123445 repeated or that 4 repeated?

Comment: @Griffey I think a single integer isn't a pattern. But couple of cases come to my mind. Although OP is interested only in the first patterns repetition I would like to know how these cases should be handled: 1212foo123123 (two patterns); 12344441234444 (44 is the first pattern but only 1234444 by accepted answer); 1234444foo1234444 (accepted answer finds 4 as repeated pattern but not 44, so is a single digit a pattern?). Tested with TextWrangler's grep function.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can take help of regex to solve this I think. Consider code like this:

```
String arr[] = {"12341234abc", "1234foo1234", "12121212", "111111111", "1a1212b123123c12341234d1234512345"};
String regex = "(\\d+?)\\1";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String elem : arr) {
    boolean noMatchFound = true;
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(elem);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        noMatchFound = false;
        System.out.println(elem + " got repeated: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
    if (noMatchFound) {
        System.out.println(elem + " has no repeation");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
abc12341234abc got repeated: 1234
1234foo1234 has no repeation
12121212 got repeated: 12
12121212 got repeated: 12
111111111 got repeated: 1
111111111 got repeated: 1
111111111 got repeated: 1
111111111 got repeated: 1
1a1212b123123c12341234d1234512345 got repeated: 12
1a1212b123123c12341234d1234512345 got repeated: 123
1a1212b123123c12341234d1234512345 got repeated: 1234
1a1212b123123c12341234d1234512345 got repeated: 12345
```

#### Explanation:

Regex being used is `(\\d+?)\\1` where

```
\\d        - means a numerical digit
\\d+       - means 1 or more occurrences of a digit
\\d+?      - means reluctant (non-greedy) match of 1 OR more digits
( and )    - to group the above regex into group # 1
\\1        - means back reference to group # 1
(\\d+?)\\1 - repeat the group # 1 immediately after group # 1
```

Comment: nice one, I'd give you +2 if I could

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for this solution. I was just wondering how does it work for `1234foo1234`? According to your explanation you check in a non-greedy fashion for match of 1 or more digits. But how come it skips the digits if in this case?

Comment: @noMAD: Since I'm using `(\\d+?)\\1` it is making sure a digit combination is repeated **immediately** so `1234foo1234` will not be matched since `foo` comes in between repetitions.

Comment: @anubhava you can extend this answer to match all repeating groups, like in 1a22b333c4444d55555e666666, by looping on find() method i.e.
`for (String elem : arr) {
   boolean noMatchFound = true;
   Matcher matcher = p.matcher(elem);
   while (matcher.find()) {
      noMatchFound = false;
      System.out.println(elem + " got repeated: " + matcher.group(1));
   }
   if (noMatchFound) {
       System.out.println(elem + " has no repeation");
    }
}`

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if you are familiar with RegularExpressions (RegEx) but this code works

```
String str = "12341234qwe";
String rep = str.replaceAll(".*(.+)\\1.*","$1");
if (rep.equals(str))
    System.out.println(str+" has no repition");
else
    System.out.println(str+" has repition "+rep);
str = "1234qwe1234";
rep = str.replaceAll(".*(.+)\\1.*","$1");
if (rep.equals(str))
    System.out.println(str+" has no repition");
else
    System.out.println(str+" has repition "+rep);
```

Here is tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 6):

My theory is that you can use the data structure known as [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) to achieve what you want.

Going through the initial string, collect each contiguous sequence of digits and build its suffix tree. For your example it would look like (for the first 4 suffixes):

```
                  R - root
      |         |          |         |
      |         |          |         |
      |         |          |         | 
  12341234$  2341234$   341234$     41234$
```

Now, the next suffix in order would be 1234$. However, when inserting, we notice that it matches the prefix 1234 of the first suffix. A counter is kept in parallel and incremented every time a suffix is added to the tree.

At each step we compare the counter with the length of the match between the current suffix to be inserted and the substring with which it matches. If the length of the match is a multiple of the counter, then we have a repetition.

In the above case, the counter would be 4 (starting from 0) by the time we insert 1234$ and the length of the match with the prefix of 12341234$ is also 4, so 1234 is repeated.

Comment: This is awesome but can you tell me which data structure will you use to implement a suffix tree in java? Or should it be built from scratch having a `node class`?

Comment: Well there's no built-in data structure for this. Basically you have to implement an N-ary tree where each node contains a string.

Comment: this can be very much used in implementing password complexities

Answer (score 3):

First you'd want to define some rules for a pattern.
If a pattern could have any arbitrary length, then you should start storing int values (building up the pattern) and starting to check for a repetition at the first repeated int.

In this case: 1234123q
You're building the 1234 pattern, then since 1 is repeated you should keep storing it AND start comparing it with the next values.

How do you handle repetitions inside a pattern?

In the case: 123124123124

the pattern 123124 is repeated twice. Should it register as a repetition, or stop at the the first 4 since 123 != 124  ?

If you choose to register those case as valid repetition, you'll need to start creating parallel patterns to check at the sime times as you keep building them up.

The firs case (stopping at the first NOT repeated value) is simple, the second case will generate a lot of parralel patterns to build and to check at the same time.

Once you reach the end of the stream you could do the search using String-provided existing methods.

Answer (score -5):

[Apache Commons Lang.](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) has a class `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` which has a method that counts the occurrences of the specific substring. It already exist, so you can use it directly instead of creating your own solution.

```
//First parameter is the string to find and second param is the String to search.
StringUtils.CountMatches("1234","12341234");
```

Comment: And how do you know for which string to search?

Comment: any string you will pass in the first parameter it will search its occurences in the second parameter String.

Comment: And how do you know the first parameter for a generic string?

Comment: ah got you I miss interpreted the question Its about the type of occurence not specific user provied occurence of a set.